# Tkinter Text widget organizing inserted text

Tags: python, tkinter

I got a problem with text inserted into Tkinter Text Widget. After inserting text does not looks legibly(its statistic data from PostgreSQL).

```
public    AO_21D670_WHITELIST_RULES  5  |1 |0.16666666666666666667
public    AO_4AEACD_WEBHOOK_DAO  8  |0 |0E-20
public    AO_563AEE_ACTIVITY_ENTITY  8  |0 |0E-20
public    AO_563AEE_ACTOR_ENTITY  3  |0 |0E-20
public    AO_563AEE_MEDIA_LINK_ENTITY  3  |0 |0E-20
public    AO_563AEE_OBJECT_ENTITY  4  |0 |0E-20
public    AO_563AEE_TARGET_ENTITY  4  |0 |0E-20
public    AO_B9A0F0_APPLIED_TEMPLATE  5  |1 |0.16666666666666666667
```

Is it possible to edit preferences of Text Widget to set it in order by tab or something? In my Code I tried to set TAB only between downloaded data from database but inserted text looks like above. Below is my code inserting data into Text Widget:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(database=baza, host=host, port=port, user=user, password=password)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("""SELECT datname, numbackends, blks_hit, tup_inserted, tup_updated, tup_deleted, deadlocks, stats_reset
                    FROM pg_stat_database
                    WHERE datname='postgres' """)
    if (bool(cur.rowcount) == True):
        statTextField.insert(INSERT, "pg_stat_database\nDATNAME   NUMBACKENDS    BLKS_HIT    TUP_INSERTED     TUP_UPDATED     TUP_DELETED     DEADLOCKS               STATS_RESET\n")
        for row in cur.fetchall():
            statTextField.insert(INSERT,("%s       %s          %s           %s             %s              %s           %s         %s\n" % (row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3],row[4],row[5],row[6],row[7])))
```

My target is to make inserted text looks like this:

```
public    AO_21D670_WHITELIST_RULES     5  |1 |0.16666666666666666667
public    AO_4AEACD_WEBHOOK_DAO         8  |0 |0E-20
public    AO_563AEE_ACTIVITY_ENTITY     8  |0 |0E-20
public    AO_563AEE_ACTOR_ENTITY        3  |0 |0E-20
public    AO_563AEE_MEDIA_LINK_ENTITY   3  |0 |0E-20
public    AO_563AEE_OBJECT_ENTITY       4  |0 |0E-20
public    AO_563AEE_TARGET_ENTITY       4  |0 |0E-20
public    AO_B9A0F0_APPLIED_TEMPLATE    5  |1 |0.16666666666666666667
```

P.S. Im a bit new to Python so sorry if question is too trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use .format() method.

```
>>> row
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>>> print("{0:10}{1:30}{2:4}{3:4}{4:4}{5:4}{6:4}{7:4}".format(row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3],row[4],row[5],row[6],row[7])))
```

Where first num inside {} is number of argument and second num is length of space

output:

```
         0                             1   2   3   4   5   6   7
```

Comment: You might mention that they will also need to use a fixed-width font, or the results still won't look right.